# Ext js panel show used to animation is not working

Tags: javascript, extjs

Ext JS Modern Theme have a panel. This panel while tapping hide and again show the same panel with animation. Now panel hiding is working but showing is not working. Any one find the problem?

`Ext.defer()` is working with alerts. Only show function is not working.

```
{
 xtype  : 'panel',
 layout  : {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'center',
         },
 width   : '30%',
 name    : 'countImg',
 html    : '<div  > <img src="./resources/mala.png"></div>', 
 hideAnimation:{
     type        : 'slideOut',
     duration    : 500,
     direction   : 'top',
   },
 showAnimation:{
     type        : 'slideIn',
     duration    : 500,
     direction   : 'down',
   },
 listeners:
 {
   initialize: function()
  {
      this.element.on({
      tap: function()
      { 
       var imgPanelObj = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[name=countImg]');
        imgPanelObj[0].hide();  
        Ext.defer( function(){
           imgPanelObj[0].show();
}, 500);
 }
     });
   }    
 }   
}
```

I want to show the panel again with animation after hiding panel. Its like slide up and slide down.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 
   var imgPanelObj = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[name=countImg]');
    imgPanelObj[0].hide();  
    Ext.defer( function(){
       imgPanelObj[0].show();
}, 1000);
```

Increase the duration it will work